# Conditions on Bipartite Graphs guaranteeing matchings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G=(X,Y)$ be a bipartite graph. I would like to collect a list of conditions that one can place on $X,Y$ (or $G$) that make Hall's condition true (that is, that for all $A\subset X$, the neighbourhood $\Gamma(A)$ is at least as large as $A$), so that  a matching from $X$ to $Y$ exists.

A few examples I have are:

1. The bipartite graph is regular (and contains an edge).
2. $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $G$.
3. Every $x\in X$ has degree at least $1$, and also that whenever $xy\in E(G), d(x)\geq d(y)$.

Which other conditions do people know which I could add to this list?

Comment: Is condition 3 satisfied for graphs other than a disjoint union of regular graphs?

Comment: Yes (otherwise this would just be an application of condition 1). I'll have to dig through my notes to find the proof; I seem to remember it took a while.

Comment: I would (so far) be satisfied with just seeing a graph that satisfies the condition and _doesn't_ have equality everywhere.

Comment: Take $X=\{1\}$ and $Y=\{2,3\}$ and join 1 to 2 and 3.

Comment: And what is the perfect matching there? Either $2$ or $3$ must be left out!

Comment: Perfect matching isn't specified: I ask for a matching from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: If you don't require everything to be matched, why not just take $\varnothing$?

Comment: We require all elements of $X$ to be matched. If you prefer, we seek $|X|$ independent edges between $X$ and $Y$, where two edges are independent if they do not share a vertex.

Answer (score 2):

4. If $|X|=|Y|=n$ and $\delta \geq n/2$.
5. If $|X|=|Y|=n$ and $\varepsilon \geq n^2-n+1$.
6. If $|X|=|Y|=n \ge 1$ Suppose that $X=\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_n\}$. Two vertices $x_i$ and $y_j$ are adjacent in $G$ if and only if $i+j \ge n+1$.

Comment: Thanks! I'd just like to query what $\epsilon$ is notation for? I assume $\delta$ is notation for mimimum degree. I find (6) a little too specific: it's an explicit construction rather than a condition that can be looked for in more general graphs, but the other two look useful.

Comment: $ \varepsilon =|E(G)|$

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few conditions that are equivalent to having an $X$-saturating matching. (This is stronger than what the question asks for, but is still an answer.)

1. $G$ has no vertex cover smaller than $X$.
2. $G$ has no independent set bigger than $Y$. (This follows from 1 because the complement of a vertex cover is an independent set.)
3. For all $A \subseteq Y$, $|\Gamma(A)| \ge |A|+|X|-|Y|$. (A Hall-like condition for $Y$ rather than $X$.)